# Why Append in JQuery does repeat in span? i want no repeat for tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to no repeat the tags that i will writing in field i try but the console appears the span value repeat like this in image how can i fix that to not repeat the tags. i used JQuery

[s://i.stack.imgur.com/dIVP1.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHGk8.jpg)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input class="add-tags" type="text" placeholder="Type Your Tags">
  <div class="tags"></div>
</div>

<script>
  $('.add-tags').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var tagsKey = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (tagsKey === 188) {
      var thisValue = $(this).val().slice(0, -1); //remove last letter
      $('.tags').append('<span class="tags-span"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>' + thisValue + '</span>');
      var spanvalue = $('.tags-span').text();
      console.log(spanvalue);

      if (thisValue === spanvalue) {
        console.log('good');
      } else {
        console.log('bad');
      }
      $(this).val('');
    }

    $('.tags').on('click', '.tags-span i', function() {
      $(this).parent('.tags-span').remove();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: for which input tagsKey will be 188? Also there are missing braces in your code. Please edit and correct it

Comment: all syntax in console is correct just i want to no repeat the tags , 188 for comma, Sorry i am still learning jquery new :(

Comment: No syntax is not correct I have added your code in stack snippet. Validate it

Comment: thanks you for the help  i approved this suggestion but i still not fixed the problem I want to write when html appears twice in the tags only once .

Comment: @SASSY_ROG any help?

Comment: Perry I can help you, but first please refactor your question. It is really hard to understand you. Please focus on what you are trying to achieve. Describe the logic of the solution you are trying to create.

Comment: Now  i want when writing html twice appears only one and delete the other please show the image in description and you will understand me 

Comment: @mkbctrl ??????

Comment: Perry please add a working JS fiddle (jsfiddle.net), with what you currently have. From what you have above it's hard to make it work

Comment: I mean, that it is hard to debug as it does not work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voila!

I have a gift for you, but first I would like to point out, that next time you should invest more time into the preparation of your question. Don't cry, don't beg, start from doing your homework first and get as much information as you can. Stackoverflow is not a place were people will do you job for you.

Right now, one can only guess what you are really trying to achieve.

After some harsh treatment let's go to the good parts:

In the following example (https://jsfiddle.net/mkbctrlll/xb6ar2n1/95/)
I have made a simple input that creates a tag on a SPACE key hit. Each tag could be easily removable if X is clicked.

[image: How it works - showcase]
[image: How it works - showcase2]

HTML:

```
<form class="wrapper">
  <label for="test">
    <span id="tags">
      Tags:
    </span>
    <input id="test" type="text" >
  </label>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var tagsCollection = []

document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 32){
        var content = getContent('#test')

                console.log(tagsCollection.indexOf(content))

        if(tagsCollection.indexOf(content) === -1) {
            console.log('Spacebar hit! Creating tag')

            createTag(content)
          tagsCollection.push(content)
          console.log(tagsCollection)
        } else {
            console.log('We already have this one sir!')

          displayError('Whoops! Looks like this tag already exists... )')
        }
    }
}

$('.wrapper').on('click', function(event) {
    $(event.target).closest('.tag').remove()
})

function displayError(content) {
    var error = document.createElement('p')

  error.classList.add('error')
  error.innerHTML = content
  document.querySelector('.wrapper').append(error)
}

function getContent(target) {
    var value = $(target).val().replace(/\W/g, '')
  $(target).val("")

    return value
}

function createTag(content) {
    var $tags = $('#tags')
    var tag = document.createElement('span')
  var closeIcon = '&times;'
  var iconHTML = document.createElement('span')

  iconHTML.classList.add('remove')
  iconHTML.innerHTML = closeIcon

  tag.classList.add('tag')
  tag.append(iconHTML)
  tag.append(content)
  $tags.append(tag)
}

function removeTag(target) {
    target.remove()
}
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

#tags {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#test {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.tag {
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 4px 6px 4px 16px;
  position: relative;
}

.tag:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 4px;
}

.remove {
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;

  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.remove:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

It is just a quick and dirty example, not a production lvl code.

Comment: @mbctrl I did not ask anyone to do it instead of me I actually tried a lot and when I was frustrated I had to ask here because I am a new student Certainly there will be mistakes But I did not ask to do anyone instead of me Thank you for helping but you are like the person who made a very beautiful cake and put salt.

Comment: And you already could not understand my question I asked if I wrote the word more than once I wanted to show only one and the other similar words delete automatic.

Comment: I am just doing it for your own good ;) I have updated my answer, feel free to use it. If it helped please remember to select is as a correct answer.